# I can't start an Intent from inner class onClick method in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have an Adapter class and a ViewHolde inner class in it. I want to start an intent to pass the RecipeDisplay class which recipe it should display. My plan is to get the position of the list, pass it to RecipeDisplay and it reads out the related element from the String[] stored in strings.xml.

I wanted to pass the intent from inner class onClick method but I got a contect related error. Can you help me which is the right contect in it?

The error I get: Cannot resolve constructor 'Intent(com.viktorjava.myrecipes.ListAdapter.ItemViewHolder, java.lang.Class<com.viktorjava.myrecipes.RecipeDisplay>)'

I tried

- Intent intent = new Intent(this, RecipeDisplay.class);
- Intent intent = new Intent(ListAdapter.this, RecipeDisplay.class);
- Intent intent = new Intent(ListAdapter.ItemViewHolder.this, RecipeDisplay.class);

but none of them works.

Here's the code:

```
package com.viktorjava.myrecipes;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.LinkedList;

public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.ItemViewHolder> {

    private final LinkedList<String> titleList;
    private final LinkedList<String> shortList;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ListAdapter(Context context, LinkedList<String> titleList, LinkedList<String> shortList) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.titleList = titleList;
        this.shortList = shortList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ListAdapter.ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        return new ItemViewHolder(itemView, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ListAdapter.ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String currentTitle = titleList.get(position);
        String currentShort = shortList.get(position);
        holder.titleView.setText(currentTitle);
        holder.shortView.setText(currentShort);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return titleList.size();
    }

    class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public final TextView titleView;
        public final TextView shortView;
        final ListAdapter listAdapter;

        ItemViewHolder(View itemView, ListAdapter listAdapter) {
            super(itemView);
            titleView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recipetitle);
            shortView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recipeshort);
            this.listAdapter = listAdapter;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int position = getLayoutPosition();
            Intent intent = new Intent(ListAdapter.ItemViewHolder.this, RecipeDisplay.class);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, save the context object you get from the constructor to context a variable.

```
Context context;

public ListAdapter(Context context, LinkedList<String> titleList, LinkedList<String> shortList) {
    this.context = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.titleList = titleList;
    this.shortList = shortList;
}
```

Then use that context to start the activity.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, RecipeDisplay.class);
 context.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `dependency injection`, just pass `context` to this `view holder` using method arguments, then use that injected `context` instead of `ListAdapter.ItemViewHolder.this`

Answer (score 1):

Change your intent like this.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, RecipeDisplay.class);
 context.startActivity(intent)
```